# Getting Multiple IDs for Same Row While Testing CRUD in Spring with JUnit

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit

I am using JUnit4 with AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests, and would like to create simple CRUD unit tests - as shown below.  However, the call to SQL update is causing the transaction manager to generate a new ID for my test instance.  Since the new ID isn't passed back during the update I no longer have the primary key for the row I am testing - which foils the remainder of the test.

Is there a way to prevent the transaction manager from generating a new ID for the book when update is called?  (failing that is there a better way to test CRUD?)

```
@Test
public void testCRUDBook() {
    Book b1 = new Book(title, author);
    BookFactory factory = database.getBookFactory();
    int id = factory.createBook(b1);

    Book b2 = factory.readBook(id);        
    assertEquals(b1.getTitle(), b2.getTitle());
    assertEquals(b1.getAuthor(), b2.getAuthor());

    b2.setTitle("title 2");
    b2.setAuthor("author 2");
    assertTrue(factory.updateBook(b2));

    // The problem arises here as updating the book record causes a new Id 
    // to be generated so querying by Id is no longer possible.
    Book b3 = factory.readBook(b2.getId());        
    assertEquals(b3.getTitle(), "title 2");
    assertEquals(b3.getAuthor(), "author 2");    

    assertTrue(factory.deleteBook(b3));
}
```

Book looks like this:

```
public class Book {
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String author;

    public Book() {}

    // NEW
    public Book(String title, String author) {
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
    }

    // READ
    public Book(int id, String title, String author) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
    }

    // GENERIC ACCESSORS (left out for brevity)
}
```

For completeness - the factory:

```
public class BookFactory extends BaseDatabaseFactory {

        @Transactional
    public int createBook(final Book b) {
        final String insertSQL = "INSERT INTO book (author, title) VALUES (?, ?)";
        KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
        try {
            int update = jdbcTemplate.update(
                    new PreparedStatementCreator() {
                        @Override
                        public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
                            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(insertSQL, PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
                            ps.setString(1, b.getTitle());
                            ps.setString(2, b.getAuthor());
                            return ps;
                        }
                    },
                    keyHolder);
            if (update != 1) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Adding book record to database resulted in " + update + " records.");
            }
            return keyHolder.getKey().intValue();
        } catch (DataAccessException ex) {
            String msg = "Falied to create new book:" + b.toString() + "ex:" + ex.getMessage();
            throw new RuntimeException(msg);
        }
    }

    private static class BookRowMapper implements RowMapper {
        @Override
        public Object mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            Book b = new Book();
            b.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
            b.setTitle(rs.getString("title"));
            b.setAuthor(rs.getString("author"));
            return b;
        }
    }

    @Transactional
    public Book readBook(int id) {
        Book b = null;
        try {
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM book WHERE id = " + id;
            b = (Book) jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, new Object[]{}, new BookRowMapper());
        } catch (DataAccessException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Falied to locate book.", ex);
        }
        return b;
    }    

    @Transactional
    public boolean updateBook(final Book b) {
        final String updateSQL = "UPDATE book SET author = ?, title = ? WHERE id = ?";
        try {
            jdbcTemplate.update(
                    new PreparedStatementCreator() {
                        @Override
                        public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
                            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(updateSQL);
                            ps.setString(1, b.getAuthor());
                            ps.setString(2, b.getTitle());
                            ps.setInt(3, b.getId());
                            return ps;
                        }
                    });
        } catch (DataAccessException ex) {
            log.error("Falied to update Book:" + b.toString(), ex);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Transactional
    public boolean deleteBook(final Book b) {
        try {
            jdbcTemplate.update("DELETE FROM book WHERE id = ?", b.getId());
        } catch (DataAccessException ex) {
            log.error("Falied to delete Book:" + b.toString(), ex);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Error looks familiar, can you post the code for Book?

Comment: @Reimeus Sure, very POJO-like. Would you like me to post the factory?

Answer (score 1):

Can you make the id an Integer type instead? It looks as if the factory causes a new instance to be created when you do the update to b2. id should be nullable.

Comment: Ok, great. id only needs to be nullable if you are using an ORM such as Hibernate.

Comment: Do you know if there is an application that can generate plain old SQL CRUD code? The generation tools I have found only apply to JPA and/or Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem while trying to document the problem (by pasting in tidy factory code).  The createBook(book) and readBook(int) factory methods were missing a @Transactional annotations; I had thought that the transaction was inherited from the invoking test container - apparently this is not the case.  Splitting the test across transactions must have created multiple instances of the row.

I hope this helps someone else who runs into the same problem.

Comment: You should be able to put @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED) at class level in BookFactory to make all methods transactional :)